# shell script: run a batch of N commands in parallel, wait for all to finish, run next N

Tags: bash

Task: run blocks consisting of 3-5 commands (in parallel/background).
Example block:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/mnt/1/x bs=1024 count=1024000000 &
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/mnt/2/x bs=1024 count=1024000000 &
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/mnt/3/x bs=1024 count=1024000000 &
```

When it's done, next block should run.
I suppose, this can be done via lock files:

task1.sh:

```
real_task1 real_param1 ; rm /var/lock/myscript/task1.lock
```

task2.sh:

```
real_task2 real_param1 ; rm /var/lock/myscript/task2.lock
```

...

taskgen.sh:

```
# loop
 # while directory isn't empty - wait...
 gen_tasks.pl # build task files from some queue
 for i in 1 2 3; do touch /var/lock/myscript/task$i.lock ; done
 ./task1.sh &
 ./task2.sh &
 ./task3.sh &
 # if task1.sh doesn't exits then exit, else loop waits for files to be deleted
```

A number of methods to check if the directory is empty can be found [here](http://www.issociate.de/board/goto/866027/checking_if_a_directory_is_empty.html), don't sure which to use;

**Question**: any better way to implement this?

P.S. Possible status reporting method:

```
 command && report_good_state.sh taskid ;  report_state_done.sh taskid; rm /var/lock/myscript/taskN.lock
```

Comment: Guys, just don't know what to say: all answers are correct, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is exactly what [gnu parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) is designed for, so I strongly recommend you use it.  In particular, look at running it [as a semaphore](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example__working_as_mutex_and_counting_semaphore):

```
for i in {1..4}
do
  echo running $i
  sem -j3 df dd if=/dev/urandom of=/mnt/$i/x bs=1024 count=1024000000 ";" echo done
done
# sem --wait waits until all jobs are done.
sem --wait
```

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps some variation on this?

```
while true
do
  ./task1.sh&
  pid1=$!
  ./task2.sh&
  pid2=$!
  ./task3.sh&
  pid3=$!
  wait $pid1
  wait $pid2
  wait $pid3
done
```

Comment: But yep, GNU parallel is better if available.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have any particular reason not to use something like [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)? If you must use bash, then consider methods like those described in [this blog post](http://insights-into-software.blogspot.com/2010/03/elegant-parallel-processes-in-bash.html) (wait and named pipes are helpful here).

Answer (score 3):

"wait" waits for all background jobs to complete. Sample:

sleep 30 &
sleep 40 &
sleep 120 &
wait

It waits till all commands are completed, i.e. at least 120 seconds for this example.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

We tried to use the [GNU sem utility](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/sem.html), as described by Phil Hollenback above, but found it too heavy-weight (300+ instances crippled the machine). I looked around for similar tools to implement a light-weight counting semaphore but couldn't find anything suitable.

So I implemented one myself using flock, it's called [semaphoric](https://github.com/timbunce/semaphoric).